# Calculating the Computational Complexity (Big-O)

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, big-o, computation-theory

```
Algorithm 1. QUEUESTUFF(n)
Input: Integer n
1) Let Q = an empty Queue
2) For i = 1 to n
3) Q.Enqueue(i)
4) End For
5) For i = 1 to n-1
6) Let X = Q.Dequeue()
7) End For
8) Let X = Q.Dequeue()
Output: The contents of X

What is the computational complexity O(n) for algorithm QUEUESTUFF?
```

The first For loop is just of n and the second nested one is of n-1. So would this make O(n):

O(2n-1) by just doing (n + n) - 1

or would it be O(n^2 - 1) by doing (n * n) - 1

Thanks for any help, I just wanted to clarify this. My guess is that because we have a nested For loop, we would have to times n by n-1, however I just thought that I could assure myself better by getting someone else opinion.

Comment: Hint: I don't see a nested for loop.

Comment: Ah.. if it is not nested then we just add, so the answer would be O(2n-1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer thanks to Smoore. Since the loop is not nested, the Big-O would be O(2n-1).

Comment: O(2n-1) is equivalent to O(n).

Comment: Hm, so if given the choice between O(2n-1) and O(n) I should go for O(n)?

Comment: Usually, one goes with a simple form in preference to a more complicated one.

Comment: With big-O you're concerned with what happens as n approaches infinity, so as n approaches infinity, 2n-1 approaches n, thus O(2n-1) -> O(n)

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent (not nested) `for` loops.  `n` items are enqueued and then `n` items are dequeued, giving a complexity of O(n) times the complexity of enqueueing or dequeueing.  If queue-operation complexity is O(1), then the procedure's complexity is  O(n), but if  queue-operation complexity is O(ln n), then the procedure's complexity is  O(n ln n).